# web scraping with beautiful soup in python

Tags: web, scripting, beautifulsoup

I want to crawl the homepage of youtube to pull out all the links of videos. Following is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

s='https://www.youtube.com/'
html=requests.get(s)
html=html.text

s=BeautifulSoup(html,features="html.parser")

for e in s.find_all('a',{'id':'video-title'}):
    link=e.get('href')
    text=e.string
    print(text)
    print(link)
    print()
```

Nothing is happenning when I run the above code. It seems like the id is not getting discovered. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not getting the same HTML as your browser have.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s =  requests.get("https://youtube.com").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'lxml')

print(soup)
```

Save this code's output to a file named `test.html` and run. You will see that it is not the same as the browser's,  as it looks corrupted.

See these questions below.

[HTML in browser doesn't correspond to scraped data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429440/html-in-browser-doesnt-correspond-to-scraped-data-in-python)

[Python requests not giving me the same HTML as my browser is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096101/python-requests-not-giving-me-the-same-html-as-my-browser-is)

Basically, I recommend you to use Selenium Webdriver as it reacts as a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a strange scrape, but if you scrape at the 'div id="content"' level, you are able to get the data you are requesting.  I was able to get the titles of each video, but it appears youtube has some rate limiting or throttling, so I do not think you will be able to get ALL of the titles and links.  At any rate, below is what I got working for the titles:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
response = requests.get(url)
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('div', id='content')

for each in links:
    print(each.text)
```

Comment: Don't we have to give the id  in the form of dictionary like this {'id':'content'}

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help for scraping all videos from youtube home page,

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    r = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
    html = requests.get(r)

    all_videos = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.find_all('a'):
        if i.has_attr('href'):
            text = i.attrs.get('href')
            if text.startswith('/watch?'):
                urls = r+text
                all_videos.append(urls)
    print('Total Videos', len(all_videos))
    print('LIST OF VIDEOS', all_videos)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will selects all links from `youtube.com` homepage that contains `/watch?` in their `href` attribute (links to videos):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/').text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('a[href*="/watch?"]'):
    print('https://www.youtube.com{}'.format(a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBhkG2Zwf-c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBhkG2Zwf-c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnn7GwqXek4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnn7GwqXek4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMKDVfucPfA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMKDVfucPfA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daQcqPHx9uw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daQcqPHx9uw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_MXGdSBbAI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_MXGdSBbAI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEW9U7s_zks
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEW9U7s_zks
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM7ZR5z3kCo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM7ZR5z3kCo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NPHk-Yd4VU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NPHk-Yd4VU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHiAls8loz4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHiAls8loz4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_mDOWLhkVU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_mDOWLhkVU

...and so on
```